# How can I compute $\operatorname{ Im} f $ of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider the matrix $\mathcal{M}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ :

$$M_{\alpha} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 - \alpha & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -1- \alpha& 3 \\
3 & 0 & -\alpha\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Let $f$ be the automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ define by the matrix $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$.

Determine $\operatorname{Im} f$ and its basis.

---

I don't know how to compute the image of a linear transformation. I know the definition is: $\operatorname{Im} f = \{ f(v) \mid v \in E\}$ with $E$ the V space from which we took $v$.

Thank you.

Comment: Since f is a linear function, the Image of the Basis is a Basis for the Image

Comment: So, the basis is the canonical basis $\mathcal{B} = (e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3})$ and $Im f = Vect(f(e_{1}),f( e_{2}), f(e_{3}))$ ? If so. The image of $f(e_{1}) $ can be computed by computing the product of the matrix $\mathcal{M}$ and coordinate of the $e_{1}$ ?

Comment: @Börge: only if it is injective.

Comment: @Bernard $f$ is injective because the $Kerf =  (0,0,0)$. What if it was not injective? Is $Im f = Vect(f(e_{1}),f( e_{2}), f(e_{3}))$ ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. But you have to extract a basis from this set of generators. Or find an equation which defines the image (e.g. the image is the plane with equation $x-y+2z=0$).

Comment: @Bernard you are right, if the matrix is not invective, that can't be a basis, because there are to many vectors in there... But what I meant is, that the Images of the Basisvectors span the Image since $f(\sum a_i x_i) = \sum a_i f(x_i)$. Therefore, if you reduce the vectors by taking out linearily dependent ones, you get a basis.

Comment: @Börge: Formulated this way, I fully agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

You should first calculate the determinant of the *endo*morphism (it is not an automorphism for all values of $\alpha$). You'll see it's bijective only if $\alpha\ne -1, -2,3$. In this case, the image is naturally $\mathbf R^3$.

For the three exceptional cases, you can transpose $M_\alpha$ and operate row reduction until you obtain non-zero rows, followed by zero rows. The non-zero rows are the coordinates of vectors of a basis of the image.

Now if you want `linear equations` defining the image, you can form the matrix with the first columns two linearly  independent columns from $M_\alpha$, and the last column the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of a variable vector in $\mathbf R^3$. The condition for such a vector to belong to the image, i.e.  to be linearly dependent on the first two, is the determinant of these vectors be $0$.

Comment: The the three exceptional cases. I do row reduction on $M_{\alpha}$ or each matrix $M_{-1}, M_2, M_3$ on its own? Could clarify to me more why the non zero rows form a basis of the image. Thank you!

Comment: $M_{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -4 \end{pmatrix} $. So $ ((6,0,0), (0,2,0), (6, 3, -4)) $ is a basis of the image? Thank you.

Comment: Not  exactly: if you operate on rows, you should first transpose the matrix (or operate on columns). B.t.w., the second column is $(0,0,0)$, so a basis of the image is obviously given the first and third columns.

Comment: For your first comment: in a row-reduced matrix the non-zero rows are linearly independent (and they correspond to vectors in the image, since they're obtained from the initial rows by elementary operations).

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. The same thing with $M_{-2}, M_{3}$  ?

Comment: Absolutely: same job (but finding two independent vectors is not so obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\{e_1,e_2, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$ (take for example the basis consisting of the vectors $(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T)$, then $Im(f) = vect\{f(e_1),f(e_2),f(e_3)\}$. From this, you can determine a basis for $Im(f)$ as well by removing dependent vectors (if this is necessary)

A proof that this works:

**Theorem**: Let $f:V \to W$ be a linear transformation and $A \subset V$. Then we have:

$f$ surjective $\iff (vect(A) = V \Rightarrow vect(f(A)) = W)$

**Proof**

If $A \subset V$, then:

$$vect(f(A)) = \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_if(v_i)|a_i \in \mathbb{F},v_i \in A\}$$
$$ = \{f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\right)|a_i \in \mathbb{F},v_i \in A\}$$

$$ = f\left(\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i|a_i \in \mathbb{F},v_i \in A\}\right)$$
$$= f(vect(A))$$

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$

If $f$ is surjective, then $Im(f) = W$. Suppose $vect(A) = V$. Then $vect(f(A))= f(vect(A)) = f(V) = Im(f) = W$

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ (not necessary to apply the hint) If we have that $(vect(A) = V \Rightarrow vect(f(A)) = W)$, we can take $A = V$. Since $vect(V) = V$, it clearly follows that $vect(f(V)) = W$, or equivalent $f(vect(V)) = W$, which means that $Im(f) = f(V) = W$ and we conclude that $f$ is surjective $\quad \square$

Now, every function $f: V \to Im(f) = f(V)$ is surjective, so by the above theorem, if $E$ is a basis for $V$, then clearly $vect(E) = V$, such that $Im(f) = vect(f(E))$ and this explains why the hint I gave you works.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see:
$$\{f(v)|v\in E\}=\{\mathcal{M}_\alpha v|v\in E \}, $$
so for $v=(p,q,r)\in\mathbb{R}^3 $, since
$$\mathcal{M}_\alpha v=\mathcal{M}_\alpha \begin{bmatrix}p\\q\\r \end{bmatrix} $$
thus, doing the multiplication, obtains points of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are in image of $f$.